# Display Dojo Tabs broken in XPages

Tags: javascript, dojo, xpages

We use the Dojo Tab Control. We fill this out with a HashMap, the title and the content.
Now we want to hide and unhide the tabs with a button. If the control has been loaded before, does the presentation.
If the control was hidden from the beginning, the control will not display correctly. The tabs with the title cut off and therefore can not be clicked. 
The display of the tabs we solve with CSJS, fadeOut and fadeIn. The area with the tabs has been hidden with 'display: none'.
Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tabcontainer can only fully initialize if it's visible in the DOM. You can work around this:

Hide the tabcontainer after the tabcontainer is fully initialized. You could do this setting `display:none` on the tabcontainer inside a [dojo/ready](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/ready.html) function.

Comment: I have a stupid question. I'm new at dojo, can you give me an example in Xpages? Where  do I insert the function?

Comment: onClientLoad (client side) is the right place for this. Another option is to add an output script element. Maybe post some of your Xpage code?